# TexWorks saving Method

Tags: pdftex, texworks, archiving

I am VERY new to Latex and coding and coding has never been something I am good at. When I compile, TexWorks automatically creates a zip file for syntex file and saves aux, log, tex and pdf files separately on my desktop. how do I make it save it all into one folder?

Comment: synctex s a gzip compressed file, not a zip archive. Tex can not read or write zip files so you can not zip the aux file you can use a `-output-directory` commandline option to write files to a folder, but it complicates the processing.